# Get Error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE" in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, windows, xampp, assets

I have problem when I want to display image

Error on console browser :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE (this is went try to display image and favicon.ico)

when using

> php -S linkIp -t public

can successfully display images and all sorts of related assets()

but because I use a filament that uses livewire to display the modal from view/create/update, it can't appear

when using php artisan serve, images and other assets() will not appear

this is my code :

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . name file) }}" alt="Preview Image" class="w-10 h-10 object-cover rounded">

{{-- for storage: link has been done, even by creating a new it still doesn't work, even the path is correct --}}
```

And this is when using

> php -S linkIp -t public

Error when try to load modal with Filament :

> The requested resource /livewire/message/app.filament.resources.customer-resource.pages.manage-customers was not found on this server.

I am using windows 10 with XAMPP (just for database which is MYSQL and Apache)

when I try access via link from inspect image (with php artisan serve), result is

> This page isn’t working
> 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
> ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

I've been looking for this problem but found nothing that fixes it

I don't know if it's because of the browser or because of windows or the error of the laravel project

but when using wsl ubuntu and displaying images it is possible, when using windows directly the error occurs (the reason for not using wsl ubuntu Nginx is because it is slow when refresh is displayed on chrome windows XAMPP)

so hopefully someone can help and direct it gradually because I'm still so new here

Comment: does using `php artisan serve --host=linkip` work?

Comment: @apokryfos still can't, when using *--host=(link_ip)*